# 'Your point of view' vs. 'the point of your view'

Tags: difference

Could you please let me know why we can say "What's your point of view?" is correct, but "What's the point of your view?" is wrong.

I was told  "What's your point of view." is correct.
But, "What's "the point of your view." is wrong since it's a phrase, it's just unnecessary to add "the."

But, I think we can say these five possibilities:

1. "the point of view"
2. "the point of the view"
3. "the point of a view"
4. "a point of view"
   e.g, "World Stories are tales told from **a** local **point of view**.
5. "a point of a view"

So, if we are gonna replace the articles with "your", we'll get:

"your point of view"(I am certain it is correct)

"the point of your view"(I am certian that is correct.)

"your point of **a** view"(I am unsure)

Answer (score 1):

"Point of view" is a fixed phrase that even appears in dictionaries:

[American Heritage Dictionary "point of view"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=point%20of%20view)

The only change you can make to it internally is to make it plural:
"points of view"

Of your five first examples, only 1. and 4. are possible.

When you add "your", only "your point of view" means the same thing.

If you say "the point of your view", it's syntactically valid, and it might mean something, somewhere, but it's not the same expression.

Comment: 'What is the point of your view' in fact is rather insulting, questioning whether your view of whatever actually has any point. So yes it definitely means something but you want to be careful who and when you say it to.

Comment: @simonatrcl But it would not be "insulting" to say *What's the point of my taking a view on the matter*.

Comment: @WS2 - not insulting, no. Evasive, but not insulting.

Comment: @simonatrcl Not even necessarily evasive. It may be something of trivial importance, so what's the point wasting energy "taking a view on the matter".